# SAS, exclude any value that is flagged x in another column unless it is also flagged y

Tags: sas

I have multiple values in a flag column. I want any ID's eliminated that have been flagged blue unless it has also been flagged red somewhere else.

Id  flag
a   red
b   blue
c   red
d   red
e   blue
a   blue

result:
ID
a
c
d

thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
proc sql noprint;
     select distinct id  from dataset
     where id ne 'blue';
quit;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. How would I include the flag as well? so result is:

result: 
 
'ID  Flag  

a    red  

c    red  

d    red'

Comment: proc sql noprint;
     select distinct id,flag  from dataset
     where id ne 'blue';
quit;